# Como puedo alinear la etiqueda span en un input group con Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Hola tengo un modal que muestra un bloque de controles ordenados con la clase input group que se acoplan al tamaño del texto.

1.- Quisiera saber como puedo hacer que los controles label se ajusten al tamaño del control que  contengan el texto más grande. Cómo el ejemplo siguiente.

2.- Lo intente con un widht:30% pero quisiera saber si se puede calcular para no dejarlo en duro.

```
    <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Issuer</span>
    <input class="form-control" disabled="true" id="Issuer-DropDown" name="Issuer" type="text" value="PINFRA">
</div>

<div class="col">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Value Internal</span>
        <select class="form-select" data-val="true" data-val-number="El campo SelectedServicer debe ser un número." id="Market-DropDown" name="SelectedServicer"><option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option value="709">BUENO</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="710">REGULAR</option>
        <option value="711">MALO</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo tu problema, puedes explicarlo de otra manera?

Comment: @Yussef necesita que los dos `<span class="input-group-text"` tengan el mismo ancho; puntualmente el ancho del que dice "Value Internal"